# How to understand child died because of memory from parent even the signal send is "9"

Tags: c, linux, process

My project which runs 10 child processes  has some memory leak,and it is sometimes running out of memory.

Parent process respawns child processes if they died with operating system signal for example signal 11. And does not respawns in case of signal 9 because , I may really need signal 9 to terminate processes(like prompting killall -9 myproduct). .

The problem starts , when childs uses extreme memory operating system(FreeBSD 8.3 in my case) send signal 9 to the child. But even it is signal 9 I want to respawn the dead process because it is not triggered by user.

Do you have any idea how can I seperate between the signal 9 caused because memory problem and triggered by user. 
And is there any C tutorial or example code which you can advice?

Comment: Aren't you contracting yourself? You first say that you don't respawn on `SIGKILL` and then say you want to?  Also why wouldn't the user just kill the parent and as long as the children are in the same process group they would receive the signal too?

Comment: I am saying in case of SIGKILL caused by "out of memory" I want to respawn , in case user types "kill -9 pidmyproj" I don't want to respawn. I am asking if there is a way to seperate this cases. If answer is yes(there is a way) I am not contracting , else as you say I am contracting.

Comment: The `SIGKILL` signal is used to cause immediate program termination. It cannot be **handled or ignored**, and is therefore always **fatal**. It is also not possible to block this signal.

Comment: @SakthiKumar: But the _parent_ process can restart the child if it dies of the signal. Your comment is not relevant.

Comment: Dont you want to fix the root cause(memory leak) than the side effect?

Comment: @HAL I am working on it , but this is a problem also. All problems should be fixed

Comment: I think it's *unlikely* (though not impossible) that the user would send a `SIGKILL` to the process directly; they *should* be using `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT`, or `SIGHUP` first.  You could just take the view that any `SIGKILL` means "I will restart you".

Comment: Also I meant to type "contradicting" not "contracting" :-)

Comment: It is  often we use SIGKILL in project because SIGTERM is taking a long time for shutting down. Shutting down duralation is a issue for us.

Comment: @trojanfoe  I wish I wouldn't copy paste directly :) thanks for warning anyways .

Comment: 0) fix the leak 1) don't use SIGKILL 2) if sigterm is _taking too long_: alter the handler for SIGTERM or SIGQUIT 3) the parent could inspect the rusage for the child after the wait3() function. Probably the `ru_maxrss` will be usable as information source for some heuristic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. And you should really fix the problem. Most computers will grind to screeching halt before the OOM killer kicks in and frees up the memory. The users will not like you if you rely on OOM killer to restart your application now and than.

Now to the signal. Manually you can always kill the *parent*, no? So when the child is killed, but the parent is not, you can always restart it. It does not prevent you from killing the children completely. Also kill by default sends signal SIGTERM and system never sends that on error, so you can use that for terminating the application.

Answer (score 1):

**First of all you should fix the memory leak. There is no other workaroud.**

To identify the source of a signal:

Please refer to `sigaction(2)`. The `siginfo_t` argument to `sa_sigaction` is a `struct` with the following elements:

```
       siginfo_t {
           int      si_signo;    /* Signal number */
           int      si_errno;    /* An errno value */
           int      si_code;     /* Signal code */
           int      si_trapno;   /* Trap number that caused
                                    hardware-generated signal
                                    (unused on most architectures) */
           pid_t    si_pid;      /* Sending process ID */
           uid_t    si_uid;      /* Real user ID of sending process */
           int      si_status;   /* Exit value or signal */
           clock_t  si_utime;    /* User time consumed */
           clock_t  si_stime;    /* System time consumed */
           sigval_t si_value;    /* Signal value */
           int      si_int;      /* POSIX.1b signal */
           void    *si_ptr;      /* POSIX.1b signal */
           int      si_overrun;  /* Timer overrun count; POSIX.1b timers */
           int      si_timerid;  /* Timer ID; POSIX.1b timers */
           void    *si_addr;     /* Memory location which caused fault */
           long     si_band;     /* Band event (was int in
                                    glibc 2.3.2 and earlier) */
           int      si_fd;       /* File descriptor */
           short    si_addr_lsb; /* Least significant bit of address
                                    (since kernel 2.6.32) */
       }
```

You can identify the source as follows:

```
static void signal_handler(int sig, siginfo_t *siginfo, void *context)
{
    printf ("Sending PID: %ld, UID: %ld\n", (long)siginfo->si_pid,(long)siginfo->si_uid);
}
```

However, `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be intercepted and handled.